# Are "backwards" terminators for if and case unique to shell scripting?

Tags: syntax, shell, bash

In bash at least, `if` and `case` blocks are closed like this:

```
if some-expr
then
    echo "hello world"
fi

case $some-var in
[1-5])
    do-a-thing
    ;;
*)
    do-another-thing
esac
```

as opposed to the more typical close of `end` or `endif`/`endcase`. As far as I know, this rather funny convention is unique to shell scripting and I have never seen such an odd block terminator anywhere else. Sometimes things like this have an origin in another language (like Ruby's `elsif` coming from Perl), or a strange justification. Does this feature of shell scripting have a story behind it? Is it found in other languages?

Comment: It appeared in Algol68 somewhere in the 1960s.  I'm not sure who's idea it was.  If you dig through http://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/text/algol/algol_bulletin you might be able to spot who.  A few other languages do use it, eg http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maple_%28software%29 has it hidden as an alternative.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, the [`sh` program reused the syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell#Features_of_the_original_version) from [ALGOL 68](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL_68#Bold_symbols_and_reserved_words).

> Stephen Bourne carried into this shell some aspects of the ALGOL 68C compiler that he had been working on at Cambridge University. Notably he reused portions of ALGOL 68's "if ~ then ~ elif ~ else ~ fi", "case ~ in ~ esac" and "for ~ while ~ do ~ od" (using done instead of od) clauses in the common Unix Bourne shell syntax.

Since Bash was the GNU replacement of `sh`, it reused the same syntax for backwards compatibility.

Comment: I guess Bourne used `done` rather than `od` because `od` is a command (octal dump).

Answer (score 6):

No. You find these "reversed" language constructs in many languages:

- `{` and `}`,
- `/*` and `*/`
- `(*` and `*)`

:)

Comment: Not to mention the "ohm" and the "mho"... :-)